# JS format in the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's assume I have a controller action that whenever you try to access it via a js format, I want to render nothing.

```
def no_js_please
  # there isn't a no_js_please partial or view
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { # render a template }
    format.json { render json: {valid: true} }
    format.js { render nothing: true, status: :not_found }
  end
end
```

When you access the endpoint via html or JSON, it works just fine. When you try to access it via JS it doesn't work. However, it does actually execute the block, because if I add a `binding.pry` within the js block, it gets picked up.

However, this does work:

```
def no_js_please
  if request.format.js?
    render nothing: true, status: :not_found
  end
end
```

So what's the difference between the two?

**EDIT**

As a human mentioned below, what's the actual error? So, in this particular case, it raises a `ActionController::InvalidCrossOriginRequest`.

Comment: Can you define "_When you try to access it via JS it doesn't work_"? Does it raise an error in Rails or in the browser (i.e. the server sends back some invalid JS response)?

Comment: Render doesn't stop your block from executing it simply passes the information to the view and continues on in the controller.  In your no_js_please method it is doing the same thing however it is hitting its end line and returning there.  You should add a 'return false' after the render js to halt the controller execution.

Comment: @bkunzi01there is no view to pass the info to. I've tried an explicit return within the block before but it didn't work

Comment: Which version of Rails are you using?

Comment: do you have any after filter?

Answer (score 0):

Use "head" instead of "render nothing: true". The latter is actually deprecated in Rails 5+ anyway.

```
def no_js_please
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { # render a template }
    format.json { render json: {valid: true} }
    format.js { head :not_found }
  end
end
```

This will get you the result you're looking for and it will be one less line to change when you upgrade.